# Can you expose Marketing Cloud SubscriberID in link?

Tags: marketing-cloud, subscriber

is it a security issue if I expose SubscriberID of a subscriber inside email link that I send to them? Subscribers would see only SubscriberID assigned to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The severity of the "security issue" highly depends on the purpose of the SubscriberID being there in first place.  If this is purely for achieving a unique matching of a subscriber to e.g. Google Analytics 360 - this is all fine, and the default integration indeed makes use of the ID being appended to the URL.

But, as SubscriberID is numerical, it is way too easy to replace the value with a random one, hence impersonating another Subscriber on the platform. If you are using to identify the visitor on your website, exposing information intended only for the specific subscriber, then including the SubscriberID should be avoided. Rather you should work with a hashed value, utilising e.g. [SHA256](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/SHA256.html) function of ampscript.